# SQL works in Athena Engine v1 but not v2

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a SQL query embedded into a system that has worked successfully until now in Athena with engine version 1.  However it fails in engine version 2 and I haven't been able to work out why.

Here is a generalised version of the SQL.  It sums the number of people in 3 groups: adults, NY residents and the overlap of the two. (NY adults).

In version 1 this works, but in v2 I get the error "column z.id_field cannot be resolved"

```
WITH BASE AS (SELECT person_id, age, state
              FROM people 
              WHERE gender  = 'male'
                 )

    ,group_a as (
SELECT distinct (person_id) as id_field
FROM BASE
WHERE age > 17
),
  
  group_b as (
SELECT distinct (person_id) as id_field
FROM BASE
WHERE state = 'NY'
)


SELECT CASE WHEN z.id_field is null then 'group_b_only' WHEN r.id_field is null then 'group_a_only' ELSE 'Overlap' END as group
      , COUNT (coalesce (z.id_field, r.id_field)) as count
FROM group_a AS z FULL OUTER JOIN group_b as r USING (id_field)
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: I don't know Athena but in some databases I've seen USING (id_field) to collapse z.id_field and r.id_field into a single column id_field not attached to either z or r. Try just id_field without the z prefix.

Comment: @Rup . . . Both should be supported with `using`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd have thought so too but I've just found it again. This was Oracle 19c, ORA-25154 column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier.

Comment: @Rup . . . That is really, really weird.  How are you supposed to check if there is a match in the outer `join`?  [I'm not expecting you to answer that question.]

Answer (score 0):

As a note, in *any* database this would be simpler as an aggregation and probably faster too:

```
SELECT grp, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT person_id,
             (CASE WHEN MAX(age) > 17 AND MAX(state) = 'NY' THEN 'Both'
                   WHEN MAX(age) > 17 THEN 'Age Only'
                   ELSE 'State Only'
              END) as grp
      FROM people 
      WHERE gender  = 'male' AND
            (age > 17 OR state = 'NY')
      GROUP BY person_id
     ) x
GROUP BY grp;
```

The above assumes that `person_id` can be repeated in `people`.  If that is not the case, then this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age > 17 AND state = 'NY' THEN 'Both'
             WHEN age > 17 THEN 'Age Only'
             ELSE 'State Only'
         END) as grp, COUNT(*)
FROM people 
WHERE gender  = 'male' AND
      (age > 17 OR state = 'NY')
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it was structured in this way so that c# code could easily edit the SQL to change the definitions of group_a and group_b.  The SQL I've posted is much simplified to demonstrate the Athena error message.

Comment: @Bill0688 . . . This structure is also pretty easy to change -- and could probably be made even simpler if the goal is to pass in the values once.